# Gradle failing to resolve dependencies over https + basic auth

Tags: android, ssl, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

**Update:** *Removing the Google public DNS servers from my router's WAN configuration seems to have fixed this. Can anyone explain why, though?*

*Note: The app name, company name, packages, urls, and library names are redacted below.*

I have a couple of libraries (one and two), which are hosted on a private maven repository over https and protected with basic authentication. This maven repo is not located in the office. It is cloud hosted.

I have the authentication info in my build script and it has previously worked both from home and from the office. My app depends on libraries `one` and `two`. The versions happen to be in sync so you'll have to look for the names in the logs below.

This private maven repo is *not behind a VPN*. I have been able to connect and download my dependencies without issues for the past year or more. I can still get them fine from within the office, but not from home (Neither Linux nor Windows can do this for me at home).

Up until this point, it's my problem, right? Here's the anomaly: I can copy-paste the url in my browser and download the referenced `maven-metadata.xml` without issue. It just works.

So my question is: why can't Gradle resolve this?

Here's the log:

```
./gradlew tasks
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
versionName: x.xx.xx
versionCode: xxxxxx
Timestamp: 2015/Aug/26 11:19

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':appname'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':appname:_compile'.
   > Could not resolve com.group:one:3.02.00-SNAPSHOT.
     Required by:
         project:appname:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.group:one:3.02.00-SNAPSHOT.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://redacted.maven.url/repository/internal/com/group/one/3.02.00-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'https://redacted.maven.url/repository/internal/com/group/one/3.02.00-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > peer not authenticated
      > Could not resolve com.group:one:3.02.00-SNAPSHOT.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://redacted.maven.url/repository/snapshots/com/group/one/3.02.00-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'https://redacted.maven.url/repository/snapshots/com/group/one/3.02.00-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > peer not authenticated
   > Could not resolve com.group:two:3.02.00-SNAPSHOT.
     Required by:
         project:appname:unspecified
      > Could not resolve com.group:two:3.02.00-SNAPSHOT.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://redacted.maven.url/repository/internal/com/group/two/3.02.00-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'https://redacted.maven.url/repository/internal/com/group/two/3.02.00-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > peer not authenticated
      > Could not resolve com.group:two:3.02.00-SNAPSHOT.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://redacted.maven.url/repository/snapshots/com/group/two/3.02.00-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'https://redacted.maven.url/repository/snapshots/com/group/two/3.02.00-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > peer not authenticated

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

increasing the verbosity to `info` didn't produce anything that seemed useful, but here is the additional info (repeat for the other library as well as the .pom and the .jar attempts):

```
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/group/one/3.02.00-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml]
```

Turning on `stacktrace` gave me a huge stack trace, which seems to point to `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated`. It's a monstrous stack trace and there's nothing say *why* verification failed, just *that* it failed:

```
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':appname'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:74)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:495)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:89)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$2.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:126)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:36)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:103)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:102)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':appname:_compile'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultResolvedConfiguration.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultResolvedConfiguration.getResolvedArtifacts(DefaultResolvedConfiguration.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyConfigurationResolver$FilesAggregatingResolvedConfiguration.getResolvedArtifacts(SelfResolvingDependencyConfigurationResolver.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver$ErrorHandlingResolvedConfiguration.getResolvedArtifacts(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:221)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.collectArtifacts(DependencyManager.java:685)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.resolveDependencyForConfig(DependencyManager.java:250)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.resolveDependencies(DependencyManager.java:135)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager.resolveDependencies(TaskManager.java:318)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$8.call(VariantManager.java:573)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager$8.call(VariantManager.java:570)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:48)
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$record.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders.record(SpanRecorders.groovy:69)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createVariantData(VariantManager.java:569)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createVariantDataForProductFlavors(VariantManager.java:722)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.populateVariantDataList(VariantManager.java:466)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createAndroidTasks(VariantManager.java:258)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createAndroidTasks_closure15.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:483)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createAndroidTasks_closure15.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders$2.call(SpanRecorders.groovy:52)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:48)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders.record(SpanRecorders.groovy:54)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.groovy:482)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure13_closure17.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:415)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure13_closure17.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders$2.call(SpanRecorders.groovy:52)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:48)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.profile.SpanRecorders.record(SpanRecorders.groovy:54)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$_createTasks_closure13.doCall(BasePlugin.groovy:414)
    at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:40)
    at org.gradle.listener.ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.dispatch(ClosureBackedMethodInvocationDispatch.java:25)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.group:one:3.02.00-SNAPSHOT.
Required by:
    project:appname:unspecified
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolveModule(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:83)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.ComponentResolversChain$ComponentMetaDataResolverChain.resolve(ComponentResolversChain.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.clientmodule.ClientModuleResolver.resolve(ClientModuleResolver.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$ModuleVersionResolveState.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:560)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$ModuleVersionResolveState.getMetaData(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:570)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.calculateTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:256)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.attachToTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:230)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:137)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver$1.execute(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:90)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver$1.execute(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:137)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.run(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:192)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:175)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:106)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:187)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolve(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyConfigurationResolver.resolve(SelfResolvingDependencyConfigurationResolver.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.resolve(ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolve(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:359)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveNow(DefaultConfiguration.java:334)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getResolvedConfiguration(DefaultConfiguration.java:327)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getResolvedConfiguration(Unknown Source)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.group:one:3.02.00-SNAPSHOT.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ComponentMetaDataResolveState.process(ComponentMetaDataResolveState.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ComponentMetaDataResolveState.resolve(ComponentMetaDataResolveState.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.findBestMatch(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:116)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.findBestMatch(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolveModule(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:72)
    ... 108 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://redacted.maven.url/repository/internal/com/group/one/3.02.00-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenMetadataLoader.load(MavenMetadataLoader.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver.parseMavenMetadata(MavenResolver.java:174)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver.findUniqueSnapshotVersion(MavenResolver.java:153)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver.doResolveComponentMetaData(MavenResolver.java:78)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$RemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ExternalResourceResolver.java:408)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository$LockReleasingRepositoryAccess$2.run(CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository.java:71)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:242)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:313)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:114)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheFactory.java:179)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository$LockReleasingRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(CacheLockReleasingModuleComponentsRepository.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$ResolveAndCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:297)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(BaseModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository$CachedAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(InMemoryCachedModuleComponentRepository.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:89)
    ... 113 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://redacted.maven.url/repository/internal/com/group/one/3.02.00-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:83)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRawGet(HttpClientHelper.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performGet(HttpClientHelper.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultExternalResourceConnector.openResource(DefaultExternalResourceConnector.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.DefaultExternalResourceRepository.getResource(DefaultExternalResourceRepository.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenMetadataLoader.parseMavenMetadataInfo(MavenMetadataLoader.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenMetadataLoader.load(MavenMetadataLoader.java:47)
    ... 129 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:572)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:640)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:118)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHttpRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:113)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.executeGetOrHead(HttpClientHelper.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:81)
    ... 137 more
```